# Copy Constructor Error With a Template Linked List Class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list

I am doing an assignment on linked lists using a template class.

In my main.cpp I should be able to create the list (which works) and create another list using either the assignment operator or the copy constructor. Here is my code:

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& other)
{
    Node<T>* tmp = other.getLeader(); //LINE WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

    for(int i = 0; tmp != NULL; i++)
    {
        insert(i, tmp->element);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getLeader()
{
    return head;
}
```

The error reads:

```
linkedList.C:61:6: error: passing ‘const LinkedList<int>’ as ‘this’ argument 
    of ‘Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getLeader() [with T = int]’ 
    discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] tmp = other.getLeader();
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> list;
    list.insert(0, 0);
    list.insert(1, 1);
    list.insert(2, 2);
    cout << list;

    LinkedList<int> list2(list);
    cout << list2;

    return 0;
}
```

element and next are public variables of the Node class.

Please note, that due to the nature of this assignment I cannot change the class definition only the implementation of the class.

**EDIT:**

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& other) // I CANNOT CHANGE THIS
{
    // I CAN CHANGE THIS
}
```

Comment: Are you using `new` to make a deep copy in insert? Do you default `head` to `nullptr`? Edit: This is not related to your compiler error, just my own edification.

Comment: Your error is because `getLeader()` is not const. Fix that.

Comment: Side note -- I applaud that in your copy constructor, you didn't reimplement the code in your `insert` function and instead, reused it.   Too many newcomers make the mistake of rewriting the entire `insert` functionality in their copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to call the non-const member function `LinkedList<T>::getLeader()` for a const object `other`.

Since the `getLeader` member function does not modify the object, you can make it const :

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getLeader() const
```

If additionally, you want to also prevent that the caller can inadvertently modify the returned node, also make the return type const :

```
template <class T>
const Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getLeader() const
```

In that case, you'll have to adjust the definition of `tmp` accordingly.

If you cannot fix the above issue with the `getLeader` signature (as indicated by your edit of the question), you have these options left (in order of preference) :

- use other functionality of the `LinkedList` class that can work on const objects (like an iterator eg.), assuming such functionality is available
- access the `head` data member directly for `other`, instead of using the `getLeader` member function
- use [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to cast away the const-ness of `other` before calling `getLeader` on it

Comment: Since I am unable to change the function as you said (the .h file will be replaced in the marking process), is there another way to implement the copy constructor without having to add something to the function name? Thanks for the reponse

Comment: I don't understand how you can modify the constructor, but not another member function. But assuming you have your reasons, then you'll have to make the `other` object non-const (either by defining the constructor parameter as such, or by casting away the const-ness). But prefer the solution presented in my answer.

Comment: I also prefer your method. Let me indicate what I can change and what not. Please see the edit in the question

Comment: thanks for the help but I decided to just use the member variable without using the getLeader function. Seems to work that way. Maybe that was what the lecturer wanted us to do in the first place.

Comment: @Ravenblack : which was the second option in my edit ;) Glad you have it working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `getLeader()`'s signature to be `const` would indeed be the "good" solution to your problem (and, to adhere to standards used in many other contexts, it should probably have been named `head()`...), but there is another way to solve your problem given that you're in control of the class itself.

Since you're doing this inside the class, you have access to private members as well - that includes private members of *other instances* of the same class. If you look at what `getLeader()` does, it's probably something like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    Node<T>* head;

public:
    const Node<T>* getLeader() {
        return head;
    }
}
```

This means that in your copy constructor/assignment operator, you could access `other.head` directly, instead of doing it via `getLeader()`. As long as you don't try to change the value of `other.head` you should be fine.

---

<sup>1) Note: untested. I write this off the top of my head, so it might not even compile. I hope my point comes across even if it doesn't compile...</sup>